# MySQL: check if a value is contained in a range interval

Tags: mysql, regex, parsing, range, intervals

I was wondering if it is possible to check if a string value is contained in a column given that the column contains the start and end values.

For example: if the table has a column NR with the following rows:

400-500
45-76,23-25
12,14-19,21

I want to find the row which has the value 421 in it. So the answer should be the first row.

Is this possible in mysql?

Comment: You should consider normalizing the database.

Comment: Normalize your database. It is violates the first normal form. After that, your query will be trivial.

Comment: If these values are single string fields, I would seriously recommend redesigning your table. It will be tough parsing these strings without using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You should have two tables: one for columns, one for column ranges. With that, a simple query will retrieve what you need.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    foo_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (foo_id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE foo_range (
    foo_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    column_from INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    column_to INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    INDEX foo_range_fk1 (foo_id),
    CONSTRAINT foo_range_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo (foo_id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO foo(foo_id)
VALUES (1), (2), (3);

INSERT INTO foo_range(foo_id, column_from, column_to)
VALUES (1, 400, 500), (2, 45, 74), (2, 23, 25), (3, 12, 14), (3, 19, 21);

SELECT foo_id
FROM foo_range
WHERE 421 BETWEEN column_from AND column_to;
```

And, actually, the main table is not even necessary unless you want to store additional data :)

If you are stuck with the other DB design, you'll probably have to retrieve all rows and use your client side language to do the matching.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above comments.
Add two columns to your table and update it using substring_index() function

```
update table
set lft_value = substring_index(value,'-',1),
rgt_value = substring_index(value,'-',-1)
```

If everything works fine remove your original values.
Now it will be very simple to find values within lower and upper limits.

edit. Keeping your table structure the query would become:

```
select * from table
where 421 between
substring_index(value,'-',1),
and substring_index(value,'-',-1)
```

but I don't like this solution.

Comment: You're all right the solution is to redesign my table, but the problem is that it would be extremely hard to do so.

The actual table I want to modify is a many to many table that links 2 other tables. It also has a TYPE (String) column. According to what type the row is it has some values in an INFO column. 

Now for only one single type I have values under this format with range that I need.

The table already has over 20k rows and it will continue to get bigger.

Comment: I don't know if it would be a good idea to add 2 more column just for range. There are only about 500 rows out of 20k which are of the TYPE I'm talking about.

The current solutions so far are adding 2 more columns, post process the results after I query using a regex on the application side or somehow parse the field and do it all from a query.

I'm not sure what I should do. The best solution is to find some nice query to get what I want but I haven't found anything near what I need on the net.

Thanks all for your help :)