# MySQL Interval() on subquery

Tags: mysql, intervals

I have a table with a list of ranks for a character, each associated with a numeric value (xp). Higher the rank is more XP is needed. I would like to know the easiest way to construct a query to find to which rank the character belongs.
The idea is to use it is a subquery, so when selecting the character

```
SELECT name, xp FROM characters
```

I would be able to get the character *rank* based on the amount of *XP*. If I use two columns in the ranks table for min and max XP needed it is easy:

```
SELECT
  name, xp
  (SELECT rank FROM ranks WHERE xp BETWEEN xp_min AND xp_max) as rank
FROM characters
```

but I'd like to have it done with just one column for the lower boundary of rank

**UPDATE:**
looks like `INTERVAL` here is a red herring, keeping it for search purposes

I could use `INTERVAL()` function ([MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_interval)) for this if I construct the query programatically:

```
SELECT INTERVAL(character_xp, rank1, rank2, rank3, rank4)
```

But is there a way to use a sub-query to achieve this? The following does not work

```
SELECT INTERVAL(character_xp, (SELECT rank FROM ranks ORDER by rank))
```

And neither does this:

```
SELECT INTERVAL(character_xp, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rank ORDER BY rank) FROM ranks));
```

Any advice?

Comment: I've also considered adding rank_xp_min and rank_xp_max columns as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995595/mysql-check-if-a-value-is-contained-in-a-range-interval but would like to avoid this if possible

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need? Here, `xp` is the "goal xp" for that rank. This query returns the `rank` that corresponds to the current character xp value.

Example:

```
character xp : 12000

name     | rank | xp
Level 1    1      10000
Level 2    2      20000
Level 3    3      40000
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    name,
    rank,
    xp,
    (<character xp here> - xp) AS diff
FROM ranks
HAVING diff > 0
ORDER BY diff ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Replacing `<character xp here>` with 12000, the result is:

```
name     | rank | xp     | diff
Level 1    1      10000    2000
```

So, the character has reached rank 1, and is 2000 xp over the goal for rank 1.

Comment: Unfortunately in this way it cannot be used as a subquery which was my original goal, so I will wait a little for another answer before accepting yours

Comment: Are you required to use `INTERVAL` with a subquery?

Comment: No, anything which would work in subquery would do. Your example works but has two columns so I cannot use it

Comment: Can you add to your question why you require a subquery and an example of how you would use it? Or are you trying to use it in the `INTERVAL` function (which you cannot)?

Comment: Tried to expand the question to give more background

Comment: It looks like you want to include the name of the rank and the XP boundary for that rank in the result. I added those columns to the query. Am I missing something else?